# How to call onSaveImage() function in rviz with a constant rate?

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I find out that I can save an image by choosing File->Save Image in rviz.

What if I want to save images automatically with a constant rate? Anybody knows how to do this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/131626/how-to-call-onsaveimage()-function-in-rviz-with-a-constant-rate?/) by [ZiyangLI](https://answers.ros.org/users/3542/ziyangli/) on ROS Answers with karma: 93 on 2014-02-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should write a node which subscribes to the image stream and saves the images.  Use the `rate` command so that it runs at a constant rate.

Or use Rosbag to save the image stream, although you won't get a constant stream then.

---

Originally posted by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) with karma: 2573 on 2014-02-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ZiyangLI](https://answers.ros.org/users/3542/ziyangli/) on 2014-02-21**:
Thanks for your answer, but I also want to record other sensor messages in a video. Like the point cloud and marker arrays.

**Comment by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) on 2014-02-23**:
Then just use a screen recorder program like RecordMyDesktop

**Comment by [ZiyangLI](https://answers.ros.org/users/3542/ziyangli/) on 2014-02-24**:
I have tried both glc-capture and RecordMyDesktop. glc-capture gives very good result but if I convert the .glc file to .avi file, the color changes and it looks blurry. With RecordMyDesktop the color is not good from the beginning.